# Variable method reference in java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am trying to create a method reference with the variable, which holds method name for some method from an object:

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
String methodName = "someMethod";
```

I am looking for way to create exactly `obj::someMethod`, but using variable methodName for this. Is it possible?

I know how to create functional interface instance from `methodName` and `obj`:

```
() -> {
    try {
        return obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(obj);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
};
```

but I am wondering is this can be done in more shorthand way.

Comment: This is a very rare case - it's highly unlikely that the Java8 syntax sugar has been optimised for this.  If this is common in your codebase, you could just move this to a helper method, and then do `() -> Utils.invoke(obj, methodName)`.

Comment: What did @OliverCharlesworth suggest is the only one way to do it, this could be an answer

Comment: @Andremoniy Not only. There is runtime codegeneration also.

Comment: If you want performance improvment you may look at runtime code generation. For example here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0610/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very rare case - it's highly unlikely that the Java8 syntax sugar has been optimised for this.  In particular, it would be impossible for the usual compile-time type checking to occur (remember that a method reference is just syntax sugar for an anonymous class that adheres to a particular type contract).

If this pattern is common in your codebase (hopefully it's not!), you could just move it to, say, a static utility method, and then do `() -> Utils.invoke(obj, methodName)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you strive for brevity rather than performance, there are [`Expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Expression.html) and [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Statement.html) since Java 1.4.

```
Object obj="example";
String methodName="substring";
Object[] arg={ 2, 5 };
try {
    Object result=new Expression(obj, methodName, arg).getValue();
    new Statement(System.out, "println", new Object[]{ result }).execute();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

But if you want to use them in the context of the standard function interfaces, which don’t allow checked exceptions, the exception handling will dominate the source code.

---

You can bind a reflectively acquired method to a functional interface even under Java 7:

```
Object obj="example";
String methodName="substring";
Object[] arg={ 2, 5 };
Supplier<String> s;
Consumer<String> c;
try {
    MethodHandle mh=MethodHandles.insertArguments(
        MethodHandles.lookup().bind(obj, methodName,
            MethodType.methodType(String.class, int.class, int.class)),
        0, arg);
    s = MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(Supplier.class, mh);
    mh=MethodHandles.lookup().bind(System.out, "println",
        MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
    c = MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(Consumer.class, mh);
} catch(NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return;
}
String result=s.get();
c.accept(result);
```

This is not shorter, but avoids performing the reflective lookup in each function evaluation.

---

Potentially more efficient is to use the [`LambdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) introduced in Java 8, which is the back-end of the lambda expressions and method references at runtime.

```
Object obj="example";
String methodName="substring";
Object[] arg={ 2, 5 };
Supplier<String> s;
Consumer<String> c;
try {
    final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle mh=lookup.findVirtual(String.class, methodName,
        MethodType.methodType(String.class, int.class, int.class));
    s = (Supplier<String>)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "get",
        mh.type().changeReturnType(Supplier.class),
        MethodType.methodType(Object.class), mh, MethodType.methodType(String.class))
        .getTarget().bindTo(obj).invokeWithArguments(arg);
    mh=MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(PrintStream.class, "println",
        MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
    c = (Consumer<String>)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "accept",
        MethodType.methodType(Consumer.class, PrintStream.class),
        MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class), mh,
        MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class))
        .getTarget().bindTo(System.out).invokeExact();
} catch(Throwable ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return;
}
String result=s.get();
c.accept(result);
```

This has a higher creation complexity, but the subsequent execution of the functions will have an efficiency on par with compile-time method references as there is no technical difference anymore.